# How to use datetime column for sample weights in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sample

I know that I can randomly select `n` number of rows from pandas DataFrame by using `pd.sample` method.

One the columns I have is a datetime column:

```
datetime64[ns, UTC]
```

How can I use that datetime column as weights for sampling?

I'd like to draw more samples from more recent rows (like this month) versus older rows (like 2 years ago)

Naive approach was just passing this column as `weights` argument:

```
df_sampled = df.sample(n=20_000, weights='order_created_at')
```

but it raises an error:

```
TypeError: No matching signature found
```

Comment: You have to write a function to map the dates to weights first. We cannot tell how often exactly you want for more recent dates (e.g. should a row yesterday be sampled 2x, or 20x more often than a row 2 days ago?)

Comment: @lpounng that's true, I have not thought about it. I guess one way of doing it  would be to convert dates to ordinals and that already would give me larger numbers to more recent dates thus giving them more weight?

Comment: This can be a way. The general idea is to think about the distribution of weights among days e.g. do you want the weight to decrease on linear/exponential basis for older dates.

Comment: Read the [`sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html?highlight=sample#pandas.DataFrame.sample) documentation , there is a `weights` parameter ;)